# Uploading a screenshot made by Selenium to Amazon S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-s3

I need to upload a screenshot made with Selenium to an Amazon S3 bucket. In my Django project, I did:

```
if not instance.picture:
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.binary_location = settings.GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=settings.CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)

    driver.get('http://%s' % instance.domain)
    driver.save_screenshot(slugify(instance.display_name))
    instance.picture = "media/websites/%s.png" % slugify(instance.display_name)
    instance.save()
    driver.close()
```

My picture is defined in my Model:

```
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='websites', blank=True, null=True)
```

But unfortunately, this file is never created into the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a way to do:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Website)
def generate_website_capture(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not instance.picture:
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.binary_location = settings.GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=settings.CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)

        driver.get('http://%s' % instance.domain)
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file(settings.BASE_DIR + "/media/websites/%s.png" % slugify(instance.display_name))
        driver.close()

        with open(settings.BASE_DIR + "/media/websites/%s.png" % slugify(instance.display_name), 'rb') as picture:
            instance.picture.save("%s.png" % slugify(instance.display_name), File(picture), save=True)

        os.remove(settings.BASE_DIR + "/media/websites/%s.png" % slugify(instance.display_name))
```

I think there is a better solution but this one works.